# What should I do to handle the interrupt of ethernet on lowRISC chip?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt-handling, riscv

I am working on the `lowRISC` recently, and I want to add `Ethernet support` for it. I have added the `Ethernet IP` and have wired it to both `AXI bus` and `Ethernet PHY`, and I added the `Ethernet interrupt` to the `interrupt wire` just like `uart` and `spi` do.

Now I am working to write a driver in `linux kernel` to support my Ethernet. But I don't find the handle functions to uart and spi interrupts, just 2 interrupts called `IRQ_SOFTWARE` and `IRQ_TIMER`(which in file `arch/riscv/include/asm/irq.h`).

How does the lowRISC chip handle the `uart` and `spi` interrupts? And What should  I do to handle the interrupt of ethernet on lowRISC chip?

Comment: What is your version of lowRISC and what is your board? There should be ["config-string"](https://github.com/lowRISC/riscv-linux/tree/master/arch/riscv/drivers) passed by loader to the kernel, it is stored near kernel (or is it already using devicetree?). Interrupts are not in the source, they defined in boot process (printed in boot log and by `dmesg`, also do `cat /proc/interrupts`). What is the "Ethernet IP", is it from Altera or Xilinx, which one, what version. Is there driver for this IP by vendor?

Comment: I am using the "debug-v0.3" lowRISC and my board is "Nexys 4 DDR". The `ethernet IP` is the `Xilinx AXI ethernetlite` IP core  and the linux kernel has driver for it. I add the IP core to the "AXI IO network " of lowRISC following the instruction in [link](http://www.lowrisc.org/docs/debug-v0.3/add_device/) . Now I am working on adding driver to kernel and I find that my `boot.bin` can not load the linux kernel correctly. This problem occurs even when I use the original code(WITHOUT any modification) on lowRISC's github. :-(

Comment: Wang, about "How does the lowRISC chip handle the uart and spi interrupts" - there is interesting commit with mention of UART irq: https://github.com/lowRISC/lowrisc-chip/commit/1a9a3043b43dac70bb3baf9cd3e6b47643fce310 "hook up UART interrupt" - wsong83 committed on Jul 6, 2016; with irq vector in chip_top.sv https://github.com/lowRISC/lowrisc-chip/blob/1a9a3043b43dac70bb3baf9cd3e6b47643fce310/src/main/verilog/chip_top.sv#L808: `// interrupt; assign interrupt = {62'b0, spi_irq, uart_irq};` which is connected with Rocket's `.io_interrupt` pins.

Comment: Where is the linux driver for "Xilinx AXI ethernetlite IP core" (https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/axi_ethernetlite.html), is it `drivers/net/ethernet/xilinx/xilinx_emaclite.c` (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/net/ethernet/xilinx/xilinx_emaclite.c?v=4.6)? What is your linux kernel version, is it 4.6? The xilinx_emaclite.c driver is based on devicetree, do you have devicetree implemented for riscv linux (probably not)? The project https://listmaster.pepperfish.net/pipermail/lowrisc-dev-lists.lowrisc.org/2016-March/000321.html was not started/finished, as I know.

Comment: Simulator at http://bellard.org/riscvemu/ has virtio and network (there is c version of the simulator - http://bellard.org/riscvemu/riscvemu-2017-01-12.tar.gz). Kernel with https://github.com/riscv/riscv-linux was used according to the page.

Comment: In lowRISC release debug-v0.3, the interrupt of UART is handled by BBL, the berkeley bootloader. The kernel uses sbi calls for console access, whether the console is implemented by UART or something else is not concerned by the kernel. That is to say, kernel is not exposed with the interrupt from UART. The kernel support for SPI based flash uses polling so the interrupt line is not used (although connected). Sorry for not very helpful on this. It is possible to raise interrupt but the implementation would not be standard.